# ring topology in PSO algrithm

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

in particle swarm optimization algorithm, there are different types of topologies that can be used such as ring topology and star topology. so if I decided to use ring topology, can I put the value between brackets 2 in the following line of code ?

```
Topology topology = new TopologyRing(2);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `can I put the value between brackets 2 in the following line of code` you could check the documentation for that

Comment: thanks@Andreas for a reply. I found some resources use this value equal to the number of particles in PSO algorithm. but I do not know why. because in ring topology every particle has two neighbors